# Android: Canvas.draw not drawing on the edge of canvas

Tags: view, touch, imageview, android-canvas

For whatever reason, my tablet just WILL NOT draw on the horizontal edges of the Canvas as seen in the image below

[image: Will not draw on edge]

Which is kinda a bummer as I need full screen access, if I try to draw on the edge it just pushes it out.

TouchDraw.java: http://pastebin.com/0cJf75bF

activity_touch_draw: http://pastebin.com/dRVHfGN4

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem same as your

you can add following code

try following:

```
imageView .setImageMatrix (matrix);

imageView .setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
```

Comment: Trying to do spring cleaning, not too sure if this is the correct answer, please anyone else who has had this issue please say if this helped or not